# Identify equal differences using C

Tags: c, arrays, file, sorting, input

I am a novice at C, and programming in general. I am trying to write a code in C which reads a list of numbers (of the form 100.000000, 200.000000, 30000.000002 etc. ) from a file named 'data.txt'. Then it computes all possible differences between all possible numbers in the list. The list is such that the same difference may occur for multiple groups of numbers.

For example, let us suppose "data.txt" contains the following list of numbers:

```
100.000000
200.000000
300.000000
400.000000
500.000000
```

In this list, the difference of 100 occurs for: (200-100), (300-200), (400-300), (500-400). Again, the difference 200 occurs for: (300-100) . (400-200), (500-300) etc.

The code needs to identify such equal differences and print the equal differences, along with the groups for which they are equal.

The code I have written is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(){
    clock_t start, end; 
    double time_used;
    /*To measure execution time */
    start = clock();
    FILE* fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    FILE* fu = fopen("output.txt","w");
    FILE* fx = fopen("diffdata.txt","w");
    int i,j,k,b;
    int counter=0;
    double a,MAX=0,MIN=0,temp;
    double *arr=malloc(100000*sizeof(double));

    //arr[10000],brr[10000],diff[10000],

    for(i = 0; fscanf(fp, "%lf", &a) == 1; i++) 
    {
        if( i == 10000 ) {
            printf("File content too large\n");
            fclose(fp);
            return 1;
        }
        *(arr+i) = a;
    }

    double *arr2=malloc((i*i)*sizeof(double));
    double *brr=malloc((i*i)*sizeof(double));
    double *diff=malloc((i*i)*sizeof(double));

    for(j=0;j<i-1;j++) {
        for(k=j+1;k<i;k++) {
            if((*(arr+j))<(*(arr+k))) {
                temp=*(arr+k);
                *(arr+k)=*(arr+j);
                *(arr+j)=temp;
            }
        }
    }


    for(j=0;j<i-1;j++) {
        for(k=j+1;k<i;k++) {
            fprintf(fx,"%lf - %lf = %lf\n",*(arr+j),*(arr+k),((*(arr+j))-(*(arr+k))));
            *(arr2+counter) = *(arr+j);
            *(brr+counter) = *(arr+k);
            *(diff+counter) = (*(arr+j)) - (*(arr+k));
            counter++;
        }
    }

    fclose(fx);
    i=counter;
    printf("\n counter is %d \n", counter);
    fx = fopen("diffdata.txt","r");

    /*while(counter>i)
      {
      fscanf(fx,"%lf - %lf = %lf\n", (arr+i),(brr+i),(diff+i));
      i++;
      }
     */

    fprintf(fu,"DIFFERENCE Groups\n");
    for(j=0;j<counter;j++) {
        if(MAX<(*(diff+j))) {
            MAX=*(diff+j);
        }
        if(MIN>*(diff+j)) {
            MIN=*(diff+j);
        }
    }
    a = MIN;
    //printf("\n%lf min \n", a);
    while(a<=MAX) {
        b=0;
        for(k=0;k<i;k++) {
            if(*(diff+k)==a) {
                b++;                                     
            }
        }
        if(b!=0) {
            fprintf(fu,"%lf:\n",a);
            b=0;
            for(k=0;k<i;k++) {
                if(*(diff+k)==a) {
                    b++;
                    fprintf(fu,"\tGroup %d : %lf -         %lf\n",b,*(arr2+k),*(brr+k));                                                         
                }
            }              
        }       
        a=a+1.000000;
    }                              

    end = clock();
    time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("\nThe time taken  is %f seconds.\n", time_used);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, my code detects only the Integral differences, and ignores decimal differences.

For example, if my "data.txt" file has the following list of input numbers:

```
100.000000
100.500000
200.000000
200.500000
```

then the required "output.txt" file contains only the difference 100, occurring for groups (200-100) and (200.5000000-100.500000)

But the difference 0.500000 occurring for (100.5000000 - 100.000000) and (200.5000000 - 200.0000000) are missing!

I have no clue why. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Urgent is the #1 self-harming word on this site.

Comment: what the f..k is this "formatting"? o.O

Comment: Aside from what is already said, you may want to look at GMP (https://gmplib.org/) for these kinds of things.

Comment: It is not urgent. If if was why go to a public forum

Comment: Floating point inaccuracy is going to be the death of you in this problem.

Comment: @SouroChowdhury: The urgency of your problem is not relevant to anyone else here.

Comment: @SouroChowdhury: When accessing an array, the syntax that you are using is acceptable: `*(arr+k)`. However, most people would expect you to use `arr[k]`, which has the same result but is more readable.

Comment: @SouroChowdhury: Additionally, comments are always very helpful in understanding what a piece of code does. For example one of your sets of nested loops does a sort. Why not place a comment before it saying that is what that segment of code is doing.

Comment: SO generally provides answers to answerable questions *very* fast already - it is designed to encourage that.  I suspect the only reason no answer has yet been posted is because you prefixed it URGENT and annoyed people.  I edited that away, but perhaps damage done. Also posting unconventionally indented code that is hard to read is not conducive to getting an answer either.

Comment: @SouroChowdhury: This may not be an issue yet, but if you were to actually pass in a 10000 line `data.txt`, you would attempt to allocate over 240 gigabytes of memory.

Comment: Even if fixed for the example values given, comparing the result of two separate floating point expressions for equality is likely to fail in the vast majority of cases. [What you need to know about floating point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Then what is the better data type to be used in this case?

Comment: It needs to be written in C, that's why.

Comment: @SouroChowdhury: What is the contents of `diffdata.txt` after running your program?

Comment: You've used a debugger on this right?

Comment: No, I have not used debugger.

Comment: diffdata.txt contains all possible differences. This file is perfect.

Comment: Rather than `double MAX=0,MIN=0`, suggest `double MAX = -DBL_MAX, MIN = +DBL_MAX`.

Comment: This old question does not seem to have resulted in a solution, but it has generated a good deal of conversation. On that basis I have voted as "too broad", and would encourage other voters to consider doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'm seeing as the root of your issue:

1. When calculating `min`, you do it incorrectly and the value is initialized to 0.
2. You then iterate over all of the differences by incrementing `min` by `1.0`.
3. So you will only test deltas that can be found by adding `1.0` to `0`.
4. This does not include deltas like `100.5`.

Note that even if you changed the increment to `0.1`, there's still significant problems with that method because of floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: What is the problem when calculating min?

Comment: You initialize it to 0 which is less than any delta you find. You would be able to see this clearly with a debugger.

Comment: How can I avoid floating point inaccuracy?

Comment: Don't use floating point numbers. Which is a significant pain in C.

Comment: Then what should I initialize it to?

Comment: I'd probably init it to `diff[0]`. Since we know that the following should hold: `min <= diff[0]` and `max >= diff[0]`.

Comment: My data file will contain numbers at least of precision up to four decimal places, like 1.0005. What data type should I use?